# Storing and retrieving simple property + value with Javascript, which is more effiecient, Array or Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

if my purpose is to write a simple code in Javascript to:
- store student's name
- store each student's score

then check a certain student's score based on his/her name
I'm thinking to assign the name & score into nested loop and loop through them to check

but is object able to simplify the process?
thanks a lot for any input

Comment: efficient in what way?

Comment: hi sorry, efficient as in code length, thanks

Comment: objects would be much easier to use in that case

Comment: If you can use the name as unique ID then use an object of objects (no looping needed in this case). But if the name is not unique, use an array of objects (you have to loop over it to get the result for a specified student).

Answer (score 0):

Many programming languages support arrays with named indexes. Arrays with named indexes are called associative arrays (or hashes). JavaScript does not support associative arrays. You should use objects when you want the element names to be strings (text), and if you want the element names to be numbers, you should use arrays.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

If you want your code to be efficient in code length, Array also has many built-in methods to get the element you want, such as `indexOf()`, `filter()`, `map()`. For Example:

```
var students = [{name:"name1", score: "score1"}, 
                {name:"name2", score: "score2"}, 
                {name:"name3", score: "score3"}];
students.filter(function(x){return x.name === "somename"});
```

The code above will return a array of objects with the name value you want.